# Mustache PHP подключение шаблонов

Tags: php, шаблонизаторы, mustache

Как в `mustache` подгружать шаблоны из разных папок? Под каждую папку создавать объект `Mustache_Engine`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo $m->render( 'index' , [ 'ads' => false , 'body' => $m->loadTemplate('body/bob') ]);`